# 555 timer monostable → simulation is not working

Tags: simulation, 555, pspice, monostable

I would like to build a simple circuit with a 555 timer, in monostable mode (monoflop). I looked at these two diagrams for this purpose.

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/555-timer-monostable-circuit.php

http://pegons-web.de/555grund.html#mmv

Unfortunately, the simulation fails. Why is that?

PS: I am currently using PSpice for TI 2021.1, which means that I “only” have the parts and libraries from Texas Instruments and PSpice – so no time-controlled switch. So I use a pulse source that alternates between 0V and 5V.

I'd like to mention that I only do this type of electronics simulation as a hobby.

Many thanks for your corrections, I really appreciate them.

**Edit:** I found this site. Now I can use a time-controlled switch. This has settled this question, because the simulation was interrupted due to the pulse source.

https://www.pspice.com/time-controlled-switch

[image: schematic]

[image: cadence errors]

Comment: Could you post the code instead of the image. It is easier for anyone here to copy/paste it in their own PSpice and play with it.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can get the code?

Comment: Code is the .asc file when you save. Copy it in with formatted code button.

Comment: I don't get an asc file. I let someone look for it. And saved the project again. Nothing,

Comment: Tell me, is it a disadvantage to have parentheses in the filename? Because I know that, for example, German umlauts are not allowed, otherwise the simulation will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your 470 ohms load is asking for a current of 5V/470 ohms= 10.6mA.
But the datasheet of a Cmos 555 with a 5V supply has a 1mA output current, not 10 times more that you have.

Why is your schematic as large as my neighborhood with lots of space between its parts? I cropped it.
[image: Cmos 555 mono]

Comment: I was just about to edit my question here, then I saw your answer. I changed the RV to 5kΩ. What I want to say: To misuse this pulse source as a "switch" – because I have nothing else – is simply nonsensical. Therefore the simulation stops. What can I do to generate a voltage change during the simulation (12 seconds) so that you can see an effect?